# How to stay in category.php on pagination?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a page where I am using pagination. Pagination < older posts, newer posts > on my page works fine. mysite.com/mypage/page/2 im getting results on same template file. Now I did the same in category.php but when I click on next or previous page: mysite.com/category/parent_cat/cat/page/2 im going to index.php... how to stay in category.php and show next page of posts?

this is how I am using it:

```
<div id="previous_posts"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Neuere Beiträge' ); ?></div>                   
<div id="next_posts"><?php next_posts_link( 'Ältere Beiträge', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
```

Comment: I am amazed why  xbfish.com/2011/03/22/… (SOLUTION) works

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the main query with a custom query on any type of archive page is always problematic, as from what you can see. You should never change the main query on any archive page or on your home page.

Remember, archive pages includes category.php, author.php, taxonomy.php, archive.php, tag.php and date.php.

Always keep the main loop and main query. If you need to alter the queries on these pages, do it with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), which is the proper hook to use to alter the main query before it is executes.

For example, if you need only 2 posts per page on only category pages, you can add the following to your functions.php

```
function custom_ppp( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_ppp' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code, I added on category.php,
pagination for newer posts and older posts is working. 
Only you need to add arrows css

```
 .pager-next {
  padding-right: 0;
 }
.pagination-btn > div > span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 21px;
  width: 21px;
 }
.pager-next span {
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) url(".....images/next.png") no-repeat scroll center center;
 float: right;
 margin-left: 8px;
}

// for previous arrow
.pager-prev, .pager-next {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.pagination-btn > div > span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 21px;
  width: 21px;
}
.pager-prev span {
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) url("...........images/prev.png") no-repeat scroll center center;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
 }

// Pagination php code

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
 $args = array(
   'paged' => $paged,
   'posts_per_page' => 9,
  );
 $args['cat'] = get_query_var('cat');
 $cat_post = new WP_Query( $args );

 if ( $cat_post->have_posts() ) : while ($cat_post->have_posts()) :  $cat_post->the_post(); 
 ................

 endwhile;
 else : ?>
   <p><?php _e('Apologies, but no entries were found.', 'tb');  
 ?></p>
 <?php endif;

 <?php if ($cat_post->max_num_pages > 1) {
     ?>
     <div class="pager-prev">
         <?php

            if (!empty(get_previous_posts_link( ' Previous' ))) {
                echo '<span></span>'.get_previous_posts_link( 'Previous' );
            }
        ?>
    </div>
     <div class="pager-next">
        <?php
            if (!empty(get_next_posts_link( 'Next'))) {
                echo get_next_posts_link( 'Next').'<span></span>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You should try to cleanup your solution and reformat the text vs code proportion